# Issue when using title attribute on style element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently I came across a very weird issue. When you add more than one style element and if you add title attribute on style element with different value assigned in title. Only the first style element css gets applied.

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
        <script src="lib/script.js"></script>

        <style title="Id-1">
          h1{color:red}
        </style>

        <style title="Id-2">
          h2{color:blue}
        </style>

      </head>

      <body>
        <h1>Hello Red Heading!</h1>
        <h2>Hello Blue Heading!</h2>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Now if you see in above simple HTML code. Following are possibilities of this code working-

1. When no title attribute is added - It works.
2. When title attribute is added with same value or no value -  It works.
3. When we assign different value in title attribute as shown in code only the first style element css gets applied i.e. h1 becomes red but no effect on h2.

On solution is to use **data-** to mark title as custom attribute or data attribute.
I am more interested in knowing what is the reason behind this behavior.

To see it in action I have created a plunkr you can visit [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gB5PssEVVAkrbEYu?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

Comment: why should it be made separate like that?

Comment: @AdityaDees Separate style files? Dynamic theme application? Etc.?

Comment: what does the style.css look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `title` on `<style>` is used to provide different subset of styles. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#attr-title)

So basically going to `View > Page Style` you will see `id-1` and `id-2`:

[image]

---

[From documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets#details):

Any stylesheet in a document falls into one of the following categories:

> **Persistent** (no `rel="alternate"`, no `title=""`): always applies to the document.
> **Preferred** (no `rel="alternate"`, with `title="..."` specified): applied by default, but disabled if an alternate stylesheet is selected. There can only be one preferred stylesheet, so providing stylesheets with different title attributes will cause some of them to be ignored.
> **Alternate** (`rel="alternate stylesheet"`, `title="..."` must be specified): disabled by default, can be selected.